# How web crawler works in Android written in python3?

Tags: android, python-3.x, web-crawler

`web-crawler` written in `python3`, `webdriver.Firefox()` or `webdriver.Chrome(Path)` allows to open the browser and extract something. But, what if this crawler (written in python) exported to Android either using `Kivy` or using some other way Will `.apk` file work? Will the browser will open there too? In `.apk` file, we cannot not allow to open the browser. Then how the web-crawler will work? Any other solution except headless browsing that can work in android application ?

Comment: Your crawler must be in Python?

Comment: @cricket_007 . Yes ! It must be.

Comment: Have you attempted to run it from Kivy, in an App?

Comment: @cricket_007  I am setting up kivy but will headless browsing will work in `.apk`file?